# Swift UITableView responding to when a user taps a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In the TableViewController I have this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tab = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(8, 80, 584, 512), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.tab?.delegate = self
    self.tab?.dataSource = self
    self.tab?.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.tab?.reloadData()

    self.view.addSubview(tab!)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = self.data.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    if let item = self.data[indexPath.row] as DataItem? {
        // cell.updateWithDataItem(item)
        // this line is commented out because the error occurs with or without this line
    }
    return cell
}
```

And in my CustomCell I have this code:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool){
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    println("cell selected \(id)")
}
```

When I get my JSON Data from the server, I have this code in my TableViewController which populates the table `self.tab`:

```
self.data = JSONData
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     self.tab?.reloadData()
})
```

My problem is that when I populate `self.tab`, my UITableView, I end up with this in the console

```
cell selected f4324
cell selected f4325
cell selected f4326
cell selected f4327
cell selected f4328
...... and so on .....
```

It is as if the cells are being selected as they are added into my UITableView.

- Is this typical behaviour of a UITableView?
- I want to stop this behaviour and have code that only responds to user interaction (not the table being populated). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes this is the normal behaviour of UITableView and UITableViewCell. To make it respond to the user interaction. You can implement the delegate method of UITableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath);
```

This function is called when the user tap on cell.

Comment: I had a segue as proposed by apple documentation but it didn't work when I touch the cell, don't know why. With this method now I can invoke the segue manually